# Oracle function for smallest possible date

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

Consider the following two functions which return the number of films a customer has rented. The second one overloads the first and has two more parameters to specify the range in which films should be rented.

```
FUNCTION GetFilmCount(customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE)
RETURN INTEGER;    

FUNCTION GetFilmCount(customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE, begin_date_in IN DATE, end_date_in IN DATE)
RETURN INTEGER;
```

To reduce code duplication I want to call the second function from the first one. For the *end_date_in* I can pass *SYSDATE* but is there a **Oracle** function to pass the smallest possible date for *begin_date_in* (<> in the following code) without querying the *CUSTOMER* table?

```
FUNCTION GetFilmCount(customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE)
RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN GetFilmCount(customer_id_in, <> ,SYSDATE);
END;
```

Comment: There is an absolute "earliest" date in Oracle (BC, several thousand years back). But for this application, why do you need that? Surely you don't have any rentals in year 1300, do you? So use 1 January 1300 as the begin_date default.

Comment: By the way, you don't need two functions. You can make the second and third parameters of the second function optional, by giving them defaults. Then if the function is called with just one parameter, the same (the **second**) function will be called, with default begin_date and end_date.

Comment: Instead of "smallest possible date" I would use `NULL` instead

Comment: You need only one function, e.g.:  `FUNCTION GetFilmCount(customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE, begin_date_in IN DATE DEFAULT NULL, end_date_in IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)
RETURN INTEGER;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NULL` for "undefined" values rather than some magic number:

```
FUNCTION GetFilmCount(
  customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE
)
RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN GetFilmCount(customer_id_in, NULL ,SYSDATE);
END;
```

and

```
FUNCTION GetFilmCount(
  customer_id_in IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE,
  begin_date_in  IN DATE,
  end_date_in    IN DATE
)
RETURN INTEGER IS
  p_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   p_count
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  customer_id = customer_id_in
  AND    ( begin_date_in IS NULL OR begin_date_in    <= your_date_column )
  AND    ( end_date_in   IS NULL OR your_date_column <= end_date_in );

  RETURN p_count;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value of a DATE variable in Oracle is January 1, 4712 BC, so the following will give you the max range up to and including SYSDATE:

```
RETURN GetFilmCount(customer_id_in, TO_DATE('01-Jan-4712 BC', 'DD-MON-YYYY BC'), SYSDATE);
```

Best of luck.